# NVD3 - Stacked Bar chart, space after every second bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I would like to insert 100px of space after every second bar in my stacked bar chart
http://jsfiddle.net/dvm628e3/1/

The desired output is

[image]

The groupSpacing property helps me do this for each bar but not for every nth one.

I have tried selecting the groups and applying a transform but getting confused regarding groups and series and selecting the  element of each bar to the transform is correctly applied.

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-group:nth-child(2)").attr("transform", "translate(35, 0)");
```

Thanks for advice/assistance

Answer (score 3):

## Problems with current selector

Your CSS selector is close, but not quite right.

`.nv-group:nth-child(2)` means the second `.nv-group` of its parent. In [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvm628e3/1/), each `.nv-group` is one of the colored bar segments, and in this case the second `.nv-group` contains the light blue (middle) bar segment from *every* bar (i.e. middle bar from JJ, BB, ...).

Instead, we need to select the correct bar from each `.nv-group`.

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-group rect:nth-child(2)")
```

This selects the second bar.

Even better, we can do

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-group rect:nth-last-child(2)")
```

This selects every second bar.

We can then apply `.width` or `.attr` on these selected objects, but it actually won't help much.

Because each bar is placed absolutely relative to the left side of the chart rather than relative the the bar before it, by moving a single bar we'd create weird gaps between the surrounding bars.

## Possible solutions

### 1. Programmatically move bars [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46gtr8aj/)

You could do this:

```
for ( let i = 1; i <= d3.selectAll(".nv-group:first-child rect")[0].length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    const [xPosition, yPosition] = d3.selectAll(`.nv-group rect:nth-child(${i})`).attr("transform").match(/[0-9.]+/g);
    d3.selectAll(`.nv-group rect:nth-child(${i})`).attr("transform", `translate(${xPosition - 5}, ${yPosition})`)
  }
}
```

The above code works and successfully moves every 2nd bar.

The chart will look weird if you try to create a space every 3 or more bars, though, because the spacing will be inconsistent.

### 2. Use space in data [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2qyjsdL/2/)

```
var data = [
    {
        "key": "one", 
        "values": [
            {"x": "JJ", "y": 0.8},
            {"x": "BB", "y": 0.8},
            {"x": "", "y": 0},      //<-- here
            {"x": "DD", "y": 0.7},
            {"x": "FF", "y": 0.6},
            {"x": " ", "y": 0},     //<-- here
            {"x": "HH", "y": 0.5}
        ]
    },
```

This adds an invisible bar. The problem is that it's the regular thickness. You'd have to use solution 1 to adjust the width.

### 3. Don't use NVD3

"Vanilla" D3 has an excellent [example on how to separate bars into groups](https://observablehq.com/@d3/grouped-bar-chart).

I couldn't find a way to combine this with NVD3, though.